# Ubuntu File Server - Multiple Users

Tags: ubuntu, file-server

In my company, we have a network with ~50 computers. All our files are stored in the cloud and I need to change it.

I already have an Ubuntu server for local application testing and I want to use it for file sharing.

The problem is, the network has windows machines, OSXs and linux.

I found everywhere people recommending samba. But how user management works?

Do I have to create users and set the password for each one?

Is there a way for the user to manage it's info and password?

Comment: Do you currently have any form of central user or computer management?

Comment: You can manage this through SMB, first time this would be time consuming because you have to set credentials for a person or group of person but you can do that by SMB and of course you have to make a centralised setting by which you can handle all this management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some points to consider. If you want native filesharing you could use diverse protocols to achieve this.

Samba is what you want for Windows clients. Even Apples like the SMB2 protocol. But they are compatible with NFS and AFP/AppleTalk. And Linux basically can speaking everything, just need the client able to do this.

About the users. You should take care of this. Analysing your question, I think that you don't have some centralised user administration backend such as OpenLDAP, FreeIPA or Active Directory. So you'll need to create the users and set passwords for them. In Ubuntu you could make users change their password through SSH or locally on the server with the `passwd` command.